# Check a type attribute with a Descriptor and a Decorator : "__get__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" when accessing the attribute

Tags: python, decorator, typechecking, python-descriptors

### Goal

I try to implement a Decorator that could act like a typechecking function. I'm not there yet since the validation is working well but when I try to access the attribute I get the error : `TypeError: __get__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

I'm using Python 3.9.7.

### Description

```py
# Descriptor definition
class PositiveNumber:
    def __get__(self, obj):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('value must be a number')
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Value cannot be negative.')
        self.value = value

# Decorator definition
def positive_number(attr):
    def decorator(cls):
        setattr(cls, attr, PositiveNumber())
        return cls
    return decorator

# class that actually check for the right type
@positive_number('number')
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.number = value


def main():
    a = MyClass(3)
    print(a.number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do you see the way to fix this ?

Comment: I don't know much if at all about Python decorators, but the instance `a` doesn't get assigned the variable `number` upon creation. `vars(a) == {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the signature wrong. When the `__get__` is called, 3 arguments are passed (including the type whether you use it or not):

```
class PositiveNumber:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.value
    # ...
```

The other thing that is wrong: there is **only one** descriptor instance, so all instances of `MyClass` will share that object's `value` attribute!

```
a = MyClass(3)
b = MyClass(5)
a.number
# 5
```

So you better fix this associating the set values with the instances:

```
class PositiveNumber:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return obj._value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('value must be a number')
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Value cannot be negative.')
        obj._value = value
```

You could also use a more specific attribute name in accordance with the name of the field on the actual class:

```
class PositiveNumber:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name  # e.g. "_number"

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('value must be a number')
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Value cannot be negative.')
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
```

The `set_name` method is only called when the descriptor is already there upon class creation. That means you cannot set it dynamically with `setattr` on the already existing class object, but you have to create a new class!

```
def positive_number(attr):
    def decorator(cls):
        return type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {attr: PositiveNumber()})
    return decorator
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. However in your last code, it triggers : `AttributeError: 'PositiveNumber' object has no attribute 'private_name'`. Do you see why ?

Comment: Added the fix for that. Descriptors are tricky beasts ;-)